# Approach when there is no y(x) in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I was wondering what techniques we can use when there is no $y(x)$ in the ODE. Specifically, we've covered singular and regular perturbations for boundary layers but there's no example with a missing y(x).

For example:

Find the lowest-order uniform approximation to the boundary-value problem
\begin{align}\label{bvp}
\begin{cases} \epsilon y''(x) + x y'(x) = x \cos(x),\\
y(1) = 2,\\
y(-1) = 2. \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: So what do you get if you apply the standard solution method, at which point do you hit an obstacle that seems hard to overcome?

Comment: The usual techniques work. You may set $u = y'$ .

Comment: @LutzLehmann The usual technique is to consider the case at zeroth order aka dropping the $y''$.

Comment: Yes. And then explore locations for non-trivial inner solutions, here $x=0,\pm2$. This does not necessarily result in a unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the outer solution you get
$$
y_o(x)=C+\sin x
$$
This can not satisfy both boundary conditions simultaneously, so you get boundary or fast layers.

These are possible at both the boundaries $x=\pm 1$ or at the single exceptional inner point $x=0$.

At $x=-1$ one would set $x=-1+\delta X$, $Y(X)=y(x)$ to get $\delta=ϵ$ and
$$
Y''(X)-Y'(X)=0, ~~ Y(0)=2, Y(\infty)\text{ bounded }
$$
which only has the trivial constant solution. The situation at $x=+1$ is a mirror image of this.

At $x=δX$ the balance and equation reduce to $δ^2=ϵ$,
$$
Y''(X)+XY'(X)=0\implies Y(X)=C+DS(X)
$$
with $S$ a sigmoid function that can be parametrized to look similar to the hyperbolic tangent, $S'(X)=k\exp(-X^2/2)$, $S(\pm\infty)=\pm 1$.

In total, after applying the constant balancing formalism of your choice, the combined first-order approximation should look like
$$
y(x)=2+\sin(x)-\sin(1)S(ϵ^{-1/2}x).
$$